# Ubuntu 14.04 Docker container: [[: not found

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, jenkins

I am trying to use Ubuntu 14.04 docker container image for Jenkins build.

I have a check as follows:

```
if [[ "$OS" = "Amazon Linux AMI" ]]; then
 echo "Amazon Linux"
elif [[ "$OS" = "Debian GNU/Linux" ]]; then
echo "Debian"
else
 echo "Unsupported OS"
fi
```

Which is returning multiple errors, similar to:

> - [[ Debian GNU/Linux = Amazon Linux AMI ]]
>     /tmp/jenkins8466974427917090854.sh: 38: /tmp/jenkins8466974427917090854.sh: [[: not found
> - [[ Debian GNU/Linux = Debian GNU/Linux ]]
>     /tmp/jenkins8466974427917090854.sh: 41: /tmp/jenkins8466974427917090854.sh: [[: not found

The same command works perfectly on an Ubuntu container on localhost.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `[[` is a bashism.  It would appear that the shell you are using is not bash and does not recognize the syntax.  Write portable scripts.

Comment: Just write `case $OS in 'Amazon Linux AMI') echo Amazon;; 'Debian GNU/Linux') echo "Debian";; *) echo Unsupported;; esac`

Comment: (Well, "write portable scripts" or "explicitly invoke bash". And in a smaller container image such as Alpine, that may mean installing it first).

Comment: @WilliamPursell That was stupid of me. I missed that check. Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the pointer on Alpine. I started with Alpine and switched to Ubuntu. I will explore Alpine first.

Comment: In both Alpine and Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is not bash (though in Ubuntu, `bash` *is* available on a stock install, just not under the `sh` name). Make sure your script has a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, and that anything invoking a shell explicitly (ie. `sh foo`) explicitly invokes bash (`bash foo`) if you want bash syntax to be available.

Comment: I have added the shebang line, it worked as expected. Thanks a lot.